# How to make an sprite action when the enemy touches the player sprite with the same color?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am making a game in which if the enemy is the same color as the player and it makes contact with it nothing really happens, but if the enemy color isn't the same as the players color and it makes contact then the player takes damage. The problem is that everything starts going perfect until the enemy of different color touches the player; the enemy of the same color starts doing also damage to the player.

```
    if hits < 3 && circuloPrincipal.color != enemigo.color{

         circuloPrincipal.runAction(SKAction.scaleBy(1.5, duration:0.1))

            circuloPrincipal.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.colorizeWithColor(backgroundColor, colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.1), SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.1)]))

            enemigo.removeAllActions()

            enemigo.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

            enemigo.physicsBody?.dynamic = true



            enemigo.removeFromParent()

        hits++

        }else if circuloPrincipal.color == enemigo.color {

            enemigo.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true

            enemigo.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

            enemigo.removeFromParent()

        }else {

          gameStarted = false

            enemigo.removeAllActions()
            enemigo.removeFromParent()
            enemigoTimer.invalidate()

    }

}
```

Comment: i meaned damage instead of image

Answer (score 1):

Try this...don't try and compare the .color of the sprites. That's not what SpriteKit is changing when it assigns a new color to your sprite via an SKAction. See the end of this if you want to know why.

Instead set a variable in your classes to store that info and compare this variable.

```
 var colorCurrent: UIColor = UIColor.red()
```

as the color changes for enemies and the player you will assign this variable the new colour.

Then to detect contact between your Player and Enemy class use SpriteKit's didBeginContact and didEndContact built-in functions.

Upon contact of your player and enemy you can call a function called colorCheck() , that checks if the colors are the same or different

I just tried it with a MovingPole class (subclass of Pole) and my Player class. And it works if I have the same colour or a different one.

e.g. my function in class GameScene

```
func colorCheck(movingPole: MovingPole, player: Player) {

    if movingPole.colorCurrent == player.colorCurrent {

        print("no damage will occur")
    } else {

        print("damage to player will occur")
    }

}
```

e.g. in my didBeginContact (Swift 3)

```
@objc(didBeginContact:) func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    let secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if ( firstBody.categoryBitMask == BodyType.Player.rawValue && secondBody.categoryBitMask == BodyType.Pole.rawValue){

        if let somePlayer:Player = firstBody.node as? Player{

            if (somePlayer == thePlayer){

                if let theMovingPole = secondBody.node as? MovingPole {

                    colorCheck(movingPole: theMovingPole, player: somePlayer)
                } 
            }
        }       
    }           
}
```

Why is this? It has to do with the way self.color works, and it seems it's separate from what Spritekit is using to assign its new colors.

How do we know?
Well if I do this, which is similar to your code in Swift 3 and look at my print statements it gives the answer. Try it yourself in your class

```
    print("Our initial color for self.color is \(self.color)")

    // Red Color
    self.color = UIColor.red()
    self.currentColor = UIColor.red()
    print("Red color")
    print("self.color = \(self.color)")
    print("self.currentColor = \(self.currentColor)")



    // Green Color
    self.color = UIColor.green()
    self.currentColor = UIColor.green()
    print("Green color")
    print("self.color = \(self.color)")
    print("self.currentColor = \(self.currentColor)")

    // Color 1
    self.currentColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)
    self.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.colorize(with: UIColor.black(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.1), SKAction.colorize(with: currentColor, colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.1)]))



    print("Color 1 color")
    print("self.color = \(self.color)")
    print("self.currentColor = \(self.currentColor)")


    // Something different

    self.currentColor = UIColor(red: 0.4, green: 0.5, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1.0)
    self.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.colorize(with: UIColor.black(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.1), SKAction.colorize(with: currentColor, colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.1)]))

    print("A different color")
    print("self.color = \(self.color)")
    print("self.currentColor = \(self.currentColor)")

    // Same as Color 1

    self.currentColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)
    self.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.colorize(with: UIColor.black(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.1), SKAction.colorize(with: currentColor, colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.1)]))

    print("Color 1 color")
    print("self.color = \(self.color)")
    print("self.currentColor = \(self.currentColor)")
```

If you look at the print console you'll see this

---

```
Our initial color for self.color is UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0.149131 0 1


Red color

self.color = UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1
self.currentColor = UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1

Green color
self.color = UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 1
self.currentColor = UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 1

Color 1 color
self.color = UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 1
self.currentColor = UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.2 0.2 0.2 1

A different color
self.color = UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 1
self.currentColor = UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.4 0.5 0.1 1

Color 1 color
self.color = UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 1
self.currentColor = UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.2 0.2 0.2 1
```

Comment: upvoted for your detailed answer. May I recommend you use swift type inference a bit more and also it is better to not use "self." on every line. This way its easier to identify when you could be dealing with strong reference cycles. Finally may I recommend you change your didBeginContact method to something like this, should make your life easier and code more readable since you don't need to write 2 if statements for each collision. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864478/how-to-find-the-collision-location/37866572#37866572

Comment: Thanks for the upvote

1. In regards to the didBeginContact & didEndContact. I agree. I had it like that in my Swift 2.2 code. However, in Swift 3 , that no longer works and Xcode wants me to convert to the way I presented it.

2. I can't replace self.color with color... so how else would I do it? 

3. The reason for the two if statements in my code didBeginContact is so I can have regular static poles vs moving poles react differently.

Comment: In regards to note 3... I realize what you mean actually. You're right that method is better.